# Adding values to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] tall = new int[28123];

for (int j = 1;j <= 28123; j++){
    int x = 0;
    tall[x] = j;
    x++;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Shouldn't this code do the following:

1. Create an array named tall with a size of 28123.
2. Make index 0 = 1, index 1 = 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're re-initializing `x` in every loop. Change to:

```
int[] tall = new int[28123];
int x = 0;

for (int j = 1;j<=28123;j++){
    tall[x] = j;
    x++;
}
```

Or, even better (since `x` is always equal to `j-1`):

```
int[] tall = new int[28123];

for (int j = 1;j<=28123;j++){
    tall[j-1] = j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you step through the code in your debugger as debugging programs is what it is for.

What I would expect you would see is that every time the code loops `int x = 0;` is set.

Answer (score 1):

You have not one, but many mistakes. It should be:

```
int[] tall = new int[28123];

for (int j=0;j<28123;j++){
    tall[j] = j+1;
}
```

Your code is putting a 0 in all the positions of the array.

Morover, it'll throw an exception, because the last index of the array is 28123-1 (arrays in Java start in 0!).

Answer (score 0):

You always set `x` to `0` before changing array's value.

You can use:

```
int[] tall = new int[28123];

for (int j = 0;j<28123;j++){
    // Or whatever value you want to set.
    tall[j] = j + 1;
}
```

Or just remove the initialization of x (`int x=0`) before the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

put x=0 outside the for loop that is the problem

Answer (score -1):

- First line : array created.
- Third line loop started from j = 1 to j = 28123
- Fourth line you give the variable x value (0) each time the loop is accessed.
- Fifth line you put the value of j in the index 0.
- Sixth line you do increment to the value x by 1.(but it will be reset to 0 at line 4)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Array {
    static int a[] = new int[101];
    int counter = 0;
    public int add(int num) {
        if (num <= 100) {
            Array.a[this.counter] = num;
            System.out.println(a[this.counter]);
            this.counter++;

            return add(num + 1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array c = new Array();
        c.add(1);
    }
}
```